# How to connect to CentOS after killing permissions?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, permissions

So I will try to keep this short and simple.

For our dev server at work, I was trying to add a new user last friday and I think instead of changing his file permissions I ended up changing group file permissions. The owner is of /var is now "write" instead of "root" and as a result (since no one is in write group "write" now), none of us can log in. I can't even ftp or ssh into the server. Unfortunately, this server is virtualised on hardware in our server room. The server room is pretty close but I would need to get access permissions to actually go in to it. We only have a small server space.

Is there anyway to get around this? When I try to ssh in I get the error "server unexpectedly closed network connection", so do all my co-workers.

Comment: Is this server in the cloud, or on a virtualisation box in your server room?  Your question is unclear about this.

Comment: Its virtualized from our "server room".

Edit: By "server-room" I mean the sever room has like 500+ servers, big-ips etc. I would have to find someone who knew there way around better than I do because I am new here. I don't wanna break more than I have to to fix it.

Comment: Most virtualisation technologies have a method of accessing the virtual console; KVM (for example) offers this via a VNC server for each virtual host.  Have you tried logging in that way, preferably as root?

Comment: @MadHatter that is a very good idea. I didn't think of that. I was mostly wondering if there is a way to reset permissions without ssh or ftp.

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but after reading logs from last friday it looks like it might be because the permissions of /etc/ssh got changed.

Comment: You can easily access the virtual console remotely but you will still have to take down the system and reboot it into a live environment (e.g. Linux live CD) to repair this. This of course can also be done remotely.

Answer (score 0):

The comments have mentioned connection to the virtual console. If that does not allow a login, you can fix the permissions by booting a Linux LiveCD, such as [knoppix](http://knoppix.net/)

Once in the LiveCD environment you can mount the disk from the virtual machine and reset the permissions. Bear in mind that the user id of root is 0, by standard, so there will be no userid mapping problem.

However, if you need to change the ownership of a file to another user you should view the user and group id's from the files on the virtual disk to get the uid and gid. That will allow you to set the ownership using the uid or gid.

For example, to change the ownership of /mnt/var/test.txt to the user "fred" who has the uid 500.

```
chown 500 /mnt/var/test.txt
```